# How to test a function passed as a prop to a child Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I am having a parent component that is used to render similar child elements. The parent also passes child some props which are functions triggered when there is a click on them.

Example : -

Parent.tsx

```
const handleExternalAccount = () => {
  actionEvent({ name: 'test123', component: 'test'})
  useNavKey(wait_flow_start);
}

return(
   <Child clickHandler = {handleExternalAccount}>
);
```

Child.tsx

```
export const Child = (props) => {

return(
   <span onClick={props.clickHandler}>
)
```

The click handler is a decent function that gets called on clicking the child's span element. But I am unable to imitate the same a I want to test the functions inside the clickHandler.
Can anyone please help in React-testing library, I am on React v18.2

Comment: What are `actionEvent` and `useNavKey`? Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example